# TensorFlow Fedetated TypeError (generator must be callable)

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-federated

I'm attempting to train a character prediction model similar to the Tensorflow Federated [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_text_generation). I'm preprocessing my [data](https://github.com/google-research/federated/blob/c54a9f5053d6316f81aa6f6d1eba61068927a33d/utils/datasets/shakespeare_dataset.py#L45) and setting up my [model](https://github.com/google-research/federated/blob/c54a9f5053d6316f81aa6f6d1eba61068927a33d/utils/models/shakespeare_models.py) as specified in the Google Research GitHub repository. I'm wrapping the model for use with Tensorflow Federated with this method `tff.learning.from_keras_model`.

When I begin training I encounter this error:

> TypeError: `generator` must be callable.

I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what is causing this issue. I'm so confused that I'm not even sure what information to include in this question for the necessary context to answer it.

Any help with what this error means or how I can overcome it would be appreciated and please let me know if more information is required to help out.

Comment: Lets add code snippets to the question to help source answers. Without more information, its hard to guess where the error may exist.